# Excel: Problem using MIN within IF - Looking for vba solution

Tags: excel, vba

I'm putting together a dashboard and would like to show when the next scheduled meeting is in cell B6, based on another sheet ("Planning & Activity"). As there may be several meetings in the pipeline, I'm using the MIN function to return the nearest date to today (there will be no entries from before TODAY, so not worried about that).

If there are no meetings scheduled, I want it to return the text "Not Scheduled".

I've started by using `{=MIN(IF(PlanningActivity="Meeting",PlanningDeadline))}` (Planning Activity is column A and PlanningDeadline is column B).

This effectively does what I want, except of course when there are no meetings planned. Then it returns a 0 for the date, or 00 January 1900.

So then I thought I'd couch it within another IF, essentially saying that if there are indeed any cells that say 'Meeting', then search for the MIN value. If there aren't any, then return "Not Scheduled".

Something like this: `=IF(PlanningActivity="Meeting",MIN(IF(PlanningActivity="Meeting",PlanningDeadline)),"Not Scheduled")`

It did work, at some point. And I'm not sure how/why, because it doesn't now.

I think in the long run this is going to be better run through vba.

This is what I've drafted, but I know it's not quite right - and I don't know how to get it to return 'Not scheduled' if there are no meetings planned.

```
Sub NextMeeting()
Dim i_Planning_Activity_tbl As Integer, i_next_meeting As Integer
Dim str1 As String
    
Sheets(“Dashboard”).Select
    i_next_meeting = Cells(5,”B”)
    
Sheets(“Planning & Admin”).Select
    i_Planning_Activity_tbl = Cells(rows.Count,”B”).End(x1Up).Row

    str1 = Sheets(“Planning & Admin”).Cells(rows.Count,”A”).Value
    If str1 = “Meeting” Then
    minDate=Application.Min(Range(“B:B”))
End Sub
```

In sum, I need this code to:

- On sheet 'Planning & Admin' Look for any cell containing 'Meeting' in A, and then return the nearest date from B, putting the answer in B6 on sheet 'Dashboard'
- If there are no meetings planned, populate B6 with 'Not Scheduled'

Example Data:

[image: Example Data]

Comment: Try to replace this: `MIN(IF(PlanningActivity="Meeting",PlanningDeadline))` with: `IF(PlanningActivity="Meeting",MIN(PlanningActivity,PlanningDeadline), "Not Scheduled")`

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that now and it consistently return 'Not Scheduled' even when there are meetings scheduled.

Comment: Can you share sample data? It would be easier to help you...

Comment: A suggestion: In a separate code module define `NextMeeting(range)` as a function, with the range containing your list of meetings as the parameter. Code the logic to operate on the range to find the nearest-dated meeting - or none - and returns either the date or text, depending. Then put a call to this function into cell B6 of the Dashboard, with the appropriate range in Planning & Admin as the parameter. I think that would make your logic a bit more straightforward, and avoid hard-coding the ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array formula for such of requirement:

`=IF(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7="Meeting",$B$2:$B$7,""))=0,"Not Scheduled", MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7="Meeting",$B$2:$B$7,"")))`

You need to accept that formula by using keys: `SHFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]
[image]

As you see, the result is correct.

Note: i'm using polish version of MS Office, so i have to use standard ISO date notation (`yyyy-MM-dd`).

More at: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: This works to bring back the nearest date when there are meetings arranged. However, when there are no meetings, it returns 00 January 1900, rather than "Not Scheduled".

Comment: Bingo. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle your problem is to just use the **MINIFS()** function. No need to use VBA for something that can be easily done with readymade functions on the worksheet itself.

Assuming that Data is stored in a table called "PlanningActivity", in any worksheet in the same workbook and the activity criteria is "Meeting", as shown in following image:

[image]

Then use following equation on your Dashboard sheet:

> =IF(MINIFS(PlanningActivity[Date],PlanningActivity[Planning Activity],"Meeting")=0,
> "Not Scheduled",
> MINIFS(PlanningActivity[Date],PlanningActivity[Planning
> Activity],"Meeting"))

It will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA-based function that will return the earliest meeting from the list. The single parameter is the 2-column table that holds your list of activities (which could be a named range).

Place a call to this function in your dashboard cell B6 `=NextMeeting(...)` referring to the table of activities. You can use this function anywhere in the spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
Const NO_MEETINGS = 500000

Function NextMeeting(rMeetings)

    NextMeeting = "Not Scheduled"
    
    Dim irow As Integer
    Dim NextMeetingDate As Date

    NextMeetingDate = NO_MEETINGS


    For irow = 1 To rMeetings.Rows.Count
        With rMeetings.Rows(irow)
            If LCase(.Cells(1, 1).Value) = "meeting" Then
                If .Cells(1, 2).Value < NextMeetingDate Then
                    NextMeetingDate = .Cells(1, 2)
                End If
            End If

        End With
    Next irow
    
    If NextMeetingDate < NO_MEETINGS Then
        NextMeeting = NextMeetingDate
    End If

End Function
```